# In each part, let TA:R 2→R 2 be multiplication byA, and let u1 =(1,2)andu2 =(−1,1).

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I think I someone understand the TA notation.. I know I'm supposed to multiply the coeficent matrix A by the vectors u1 and u2 in some mannar.. but I'm not quite sure how.. do I take each u vector and turn them into columns, then do matrix multiplication on each of them to get two vectors.. and solve the system to find out linear dependency?? i really havent seen an example like this anywhere before in my book..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Notice that $(u_1,u_2)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ and  $A$ is an invertible if and only if $A$ maps a basis onto a basis.

Comment: .... what is a basis?

Comment: It's a set of linear independent vectors that spans the linear space.